# having trouble coming up with a regular expression

Tags: regex, lua

I am having trouble coming up with a Lua 5.0 regular expression that will work for 2 scenarios.

1) expression = `"[^V]Core %d+:%s*%+(%d+%.%d+)°C  %(crit = %+(%d+%.%d+)°C%)"`
This correctly matches this string:

```
Core 0:      +45.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
```

2) expression = `"[^V]Core %d+:%s*%+(%d+%.%d+)°C  %(high = %+%d+%.%d+°C, crit = %+(%d+%.%d+)°C%)"`
This correctly matches this string:

```
Core 0:      +45.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

However, I want to be able to match either string and have 2 captures: the first temperature and the critical temperature. (I don't need the high temperature).
I tried this but no luck:

```
expression = "[^V]Core %d+:%s*%+(%d+%.%d+)°C  %((?:high = %+%d+%.%d+°C, )crit = %+(%d+%.%d+)°C%)"
```

I am in Lua but I think the regex expression syntax closely matches other languages such as Perl.
Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I really hope the temperature will never be negative :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lua string [*patterns*](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1) are **NOT** *regular expressions*.

In order to do what you want - match two different strings - you need to actually try two matches.

```
local input = ... -- the input string
-- try the first pattern
local temp, crit = string.match(input, "[^V]Core %d+:%s*%+(%d+%.%d+)°C %(crit = %+(%d+%.%d+)°C%)"
-- if it didn't match, try the second match
if not temp then
    temp, crit = string.match(input, "[^V]Core %d+:%s*%+(%d+%.%d+)°C  %(high = %+%d+%.%d+°C, crit = %+(%d+%.%d+)°C%)")
end
if temp then
    -- one of the two matches are saved in temp and crit
    -- do something useful here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a `?` after the `(?:...)` group.

There's something funny going on with the number of spaces before the parens as well -- the strings and the non-working regexp have two, while the 'working' regexps have one. I'd use %s+ there for robustness.

Comment: I did NOT cut and paste so I think there are 2 spaces before the parens. But you are right about using %s+. Also I did try the ? after the (?:...) group with no luck.

Comment: OK, now I actually looked up the pattern docs for LUA. They do not even have the strength of the original UNIX regexps, in fact they don't cover regular expressions in the mathematical sense. No quantifiers on parentheses, they are only for capturing, and none of the fancy Perl stuff. You'll have to give up on matching the optional high temp part exactly, just put in `%(.*crit` to skip it if it's there.

Comment: That's why they are called patterns, not regular expressions.

Comment: Yupp, and this gives more readable code too. And next week somebody will put in yet another value inside the parenthesis so the best way is to simply pick the stuff you want and leave the rest, that is: %(.*crit = (mycapture).*%). Or write a function that parses the complete format once and for all.